# Angular 8 Local Library import issue

Tags: angular8, angular-library, angular-ngzone

I have created one Angular custom Library which I need to use in multiple projects in different workspace. I will plan to publish Library to NPM once I test it properly locally. below is my Library code :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AppbuttonComponent } from './appbutton.component';
import { CRMMaterialModule } from '../../material.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppbuttonComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CRMMaterialModule
  ],
  exports: [AppbuttonComponent]
})
export class AppbuttonModule { }
```

And Library Public API is like

```
export * from './lib/components/appbutton/appbutton.module';
export * from './lib/components/appbutton/appbutton.component';
```

Then I link my application (in different workspace) to my library. below is my appModule.ts file code

```
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CoreModule,
    AppbuttonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes, { useHash: true })....
```

It builds proper but when I try to run application, it gives me below error:

> Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to
> common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module,
> import CommonModule instead.

Can Anyone help for this ? I'm stuck in this since 3 days.

Comment: Try removing BrowserAnimationsModule from  your library.

Comment: I have ngClass , ngIf used in library if I don't import Browser animation module then it gives me error for MatRipple

Comment: Well do what the error says and replace the BrowserAnimationsModule in your library with the CommonModule.

Comment: @IvanMihaylov : But I'm using Mat-button with ngClass in library , and for that I have to use BrowserAnimationModule  - otherwise it gives me error for MatRipple

Comment: I'm having the same issue with animations in a custom library. Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Is this still unsolved? did anyone find a solution to this? I m still having the same problem. Can't remove the BroswerAnimation module from my lib though.